# Pedal charged and pedal powered mountain bike

Tags: battery-charging, brushless-dc-motor

Pedal charged and pedal powered mountain bike... couldn't this be easily accomplished with just one DC Brushless motor or would two motors be needed? I've seen plenty of electric powered bikes. Take some fully charged batteries that power a motor and you hit the throttle and go. But when the batteries are dead your back to only pedaling until you charge the batteries back up via a charger. My goal is to pedal charge the batteries as I'm riding the bike. I realize it would take a very long time to fully charge them via pedaling but at least you could put a little more power back into the batteries for a little more fun.

Comment: What you are looking for is called: regenerative braking.

Comment: Very nice Dan! Thank you! I knew of regenerative braking but I didn't consider it because it has to do with braking and I want to be pedaling and charging the batteries back up. But... after searching regenerative braking in the questions on this site I found one called "Regenerative Braking circuit" which gave me exactly what I needed. It's just a matter of reversing the polarity of the circuit to send power back to the battery. Thank again for your answer!

Comment: I had a long comment about how that pedaling and charging the batteries was unproductive due to the conversion loss. Except when doing regenerative braking while braking.

Comment: Charging the battery while pedaling is going to be a miserable experience. Powering a light is bad enough, putting half or more of your output into a battery is going to make the actual riding slow and horrible.

Comment: Thank you "Dan D" and "whatisname" for your time and input. Bear with me here I'm new to this site as of yesterday (02/09/2015) and I am trying my best to follow protocol on this site. With that having been said... I'm getting the general vibe that what I'm trying to do just isn't piratical. With all the energy losses that are unavoidable. Though I still want to give this project a try. At the very least it will be a great learning experience. Who knows perhaps a brilliant breakthrough will come of all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small motors are not very efficient. If for example you would take the chain out, and use a generator and a motor, if each would be 50% efficient, you would end up losing 75%
of the power. I have once tried a small generator for a headlight on a bicycle, and was surprised, how much harder I had to pedal.

The regenerative braking on bicycles produces little power unless you are in a hilly area.
My approach would be a small solar panel on a bike rack. It works all the time during a day.

In a local science center they have a stationary bike with a generator, powering a 100W light bulb. It is hard to keep it on for too long.

Comment: They have one of those bikes at the SMM too. Just getting 100W for just a moment is beyond the capacity of most people that try it.

Comment: Thank you "sparky Al" for your answer! After reviewing the question that was asked by mFeinstein titled "Regenerative Braking circuit" I will be using just one motor with a regenerative braking circuit to switch from charging the batteries when going down hill or, if I feel up for it, a flat surface... to simply having fun using up the stored energy. Though I'm getting the feeling that even this setup my not be very efficient. But that's what I'm here for, to find out how piratical a Electric Mountain Bike with circuit driven regenerative breaking and a few solar panels would be.

Comment: In reply to "whatsisname" according to David Butcher he was able to design a stationary bike capable of a burst output of 425watts and a constant output of 150watts. Which still isn't very much for a consistent output but with enough research and development hopefully we can increase the efficiency.

Comment: Here is the link to his webpage... http://www.los-gatos.ca.us/davidbu/pedgen.html